# Populate a Lookup Field Upon Record Creation

Tags: apex, class

I am trying to create a trigger that will populate a lookup field on a custom object called Levvel Forecat.

The basic criteria here is that when a new Levvel Forecast record is created with a specific record type I need to update Assignment__c (Lookup field to assignment (pse__assignment__c) object) with the current active assignment that the contact (lookup field to Contact record) on the levvel Forecast record is on.

So what I have done is trying to perform a select statement to store the contact id (Employee__c) on the Levvel Forecast record so we can use that in the second Select statement as a comparison.

I have then created a second SELECT statement to select the pse__Assignment__c WHERE the Contact Id on the assignment is EQUAL to the contact Id on the levvel Forecast.

Then I have a simple IF statement, and if it passed I am trying to insert that assignment ID into the Assignment__c field on the Levvel Forecast record.

CURENTLY in my test class I am getting the error saying that there is “Too many SOQL queries 101”

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I have this methos inserted within my LevvelForecastTriggerHandler so i am sorry if it doesnt look like a conventional Trigger..

**** The method that is running all this is the "loadAssignment" method, and is also looking at the BULKBEFORE after the line that reads "if(trigger.isInsert)"....

```
public without sharing class LevvelForecastTriggerHandler extends TriggerHandlerBase 
{
//List for querying forecast periods for DELETE
private List<Forecast_Periods__c> forecastPeriodList = new List<Forecast_Periods__c>();

//list for storing all active assignemnts that are realted to the new forecast creations
private List<pse__Assignment__c> assignmentList = new List<pse__Assignment__c>();

/************************************************************************************************************
// Name         bulkBefore
// Description  Standard implementation of the TriggerHandler.bulkBefore() interface method.
*************************************************************************************************************/
public override void bulkBefore()
{
    if (trigger.isDelete)
    {
        //store parent Levvel Forecast records that are about to be deleted 
        list<Id> forecastIds = new list<Id>();
        for(SObject so :trigger.old)
        {
            Levvel_Forecast__c forecast = (Levvel_Forecast__c)so;
            forecastIds.add(forecast.id);
        }

            //Now we need to query all child Forecast Period records related to the Levvel Forecast we are about to delete
            forecastPeriodList = [SELECT Id, Levvel_Forecast__c FROM Forecast_Periods__c WHERE Levvel_Forecast__c IN: forecastIds];
            system.debug('List of Forecast Periods ' + forecastPeriodList);
        }

    if(trigger.isInsert)
    {
        //store the LevvelForecast record for update 
        list<Id> forecastsToUpdate = new List<Id>();
        for(SObject so :trigger.new)
        {

            Levvel_Forecast__c newForecast = (Levvel_Forecast__c)so;
            if(newForecast.RecordTypeId == '0121N000000U6GYQA0' )
            {
                forecastsToUpdate.add(newForecast.employee__c);
            }

        }

            //Now we need to query all the assignments 
            assignmentList = [SELECT id, pse__Resource__c FROM pse__Assignment__c WHERE pse__Resource__c IN: forecastsToUpdate];

        }
}



/************************************************************************************************************
// Name         beforeInsert
// Description  Standard implementation of the TriggerHandler.beforeInsert() interface method.
*************************************************************************************************************/
public override void beforeInsert (SObject so)
{
    Levvel_Forecast__c newForecast = (Levvel_Forecast__c)so;

    loadAssignment(newForecast);
}


/************************************************************************************************************
// Name         beforeDelete
// Description  Standard implementation of the TriggerHandler.beforeInsert() interface method.
*************************************************************************************************************/
public override void beforeDelete(SObject so)
{
    Levvel_Forecast__c oldForecast = (Levvel_Forecast__c)so;

    deleteForecastPeriods(oldForecast);
}


 /************************************************************************************************************
// Name         loadAssignment
// Description  Helper method to validate resource requests on an opportunity
*************************************************************************************************************/
private void loadAssignment (Levvel_Forecast__c newForecast)
{

    for (pse__Assignment__c ass :assignmentList )
    if(ass.pse__End_Date__c > newForecast.Today__c && ass.pse__Is_Billable__c == TRUE)
    {
        newForecast.employee__c = ass.pse__resource__c;
    }
}

/************************************************************************************************************
// Name         deleteForecastPeriods
// Description  Helper method to validate resource requests on an opportunity
*************************************************************************************************************/
private void deleteForecastPeriods (Levvel_Forecast__c oldForecast)
    {
        //Now we delete 
        delete forecastPeriodList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Never hard-code ids.